# How do I iterate over a range with a custom step?

Tags: rust, iterator

How can I iterate over a range in Rust with a step other than `1`? I'm coming from a C++ background so I'd like to do something like

```
for(auto i = 0; i <= n; i+=2) {
    //...
}
```

In Rust I need to use the `range` function, and it doesn't seem like there is a third argument available for having a custom step. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

`range_step_inclusive` and `range_step` are long gone.

As of Rust 1.28, [`Iterator::step_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by) is stable:

```
fn main() {
    for x in (1..10).step_by(2) {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Comment: cf. https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/struct.Range.html#method.step_by and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27741

Comment: Note that this method will not support 64 bit step on machines with 32 bit size type.

Comment: And if the step is half the value?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't nicely handle negative steps. Where you'd like to do, say, `(11..=1).step_by(-2)` (odd numbers counting down from 11 to 1, inclusive), you have to do `(1..12).step_by(2).rev()`, which is not quite as intuitive.

Answer (score 16):

It seems to me that until the `.step_by` method is made stable, one can easily accomplish what you want with an `Iterator` (which is what `Range`s really are anyway):

```
struct SimpleStepRange(isize, isize, isize);  // start, end, and step

impl Iterator for SimpleStepRange {
    type Item = isize;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<isize> {
        if self.0 < self.1 {
            let v = self.0;
            self.0 = v + self.2;
            Some(v)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in SimpleStepRange(0, 10, 2) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

If one needs to iterate multiple ranges of different types, the code can be made generic as follows:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct StepRange<T>(T, T, T)
    where for<'a> &'a T: Add<&'a T, Output = T>,
          T: PartialOrd,
          T: Clone;

impl<T> Iterator for StepRange<T>
    where for<'a> &'a T: Add<&'a T, Output = T>,
          T: PartialOrd,
          T: Clone
{
    type Item = T;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.0 < self.1 {
            let v = self.0.clone();
            self.0 = &v + &self.2;
            Some(v)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in StepRange(0u64, 10u64, 2u64) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

I'll leave it to you to eliminate the upper bounds check to create an open ended structure if an infinite loop is required...

Advantages of this approach is that is works with `for` sugaring and will continue to work even when unstable features become usable; also, unlike the de-sugared approach using the standard `Range`s, it doesn't lose efficiency by multiple `.next()` calls. Disadvantages are that it takes a few lines of code to set up the iterator so may only be worth it for code that has a lot of loops.

Comment: By adding another type, `U` to your second option you could use types that support addition with a different type and still yield a `T`. For instance time and duration come to mind.

Comment: @Ryan, that seems like a good idea and should work, with the struct defined as follows:
    struct StepRange<T>(T, T, U)
    where for<'a, 'b> &'a T: Add<&'b U, Output = T>,
          T: PartialOrd,
          T: Clone;
which should allow different lifetimes for the input T and U types.

Answer (score 6):

You'd write your C++ code:

```
for (auto i = 0; i <= n; i += 2) {
    //...
}
```

...in Rust like so:

```
let mut i = 0;
while i <= n {
    // ...
    i += 2;
}
```

I think the Rust version is more readable too.

Comment: Re: inserting "continue" in the loop, one would only do this inside a conditional branch even in the for structure, I think.  If so, then I think it would be OK to increment inside the conditional branch in the while structure before "continue"-ing, and that it would then work as intended.  Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @WDS that's counterintuitive busywork to get a basic feature of the language, `continue`, to work properly. Though it can be done, this design encourages bugs.

Answer (score 5):

If you are stepping by something predefined, and small like 2, you may wish to use the iterator to step manually. e.g.:

```rust
let mut iter = 1..10;
loop {
    match iter.next() {
        Some(x) => {
            println!("{}", x);
        },
        None => break,
    }
    iter.next();
}
```

You could even use this to step by an arbitrary amount (although this is definitely getting longer and harder to digest):

```rust
let mut iter = 1..10;
let step = 4;
loop {
    match iter.next() {
        Some(x) => {
            println!("{}", x);
        },
        None => break,
    }
    for _ in 0..step-1 {
        iter.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use this over `for` and `step_by`?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [num](https://crates.io/crates/num) crate with [range_step](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/fn.range_step.html)