# What is a stable way to iterate on a range with custom step?

Tags: iterator, rust

How should I go if I want to iterate with a custom step in stable Rust? Essentially something like the C/C++

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {

}
```

I've already tried using `range_step_inclusive` and the solutions in [How do I iterate over a range with a custom step?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27893223/155423):

```
use std::iter::range_step_inclusive;
for i in range_step_inclusive(0, n, 2) {
    println!("i: {}", i);
}
```

But it seems like it isn't available in Rust 1.1:

```
error: unresolved import `std::iter::range_step_inclusive`. There is no `range_step_inclusive` in `std::iter`
```

What would be an alternative? Possibly the idiomatic way for creating custom ranges.

Comment: I edited your title to clarify that you are looking for a solution that applies to **stable** Rust, as otherwise this would [be a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27893223/155423).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a range with a custom step?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893223/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-with-a-custom-step)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Rust 1.28+

[`Iterator::step_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by) is now stable:

```
fn main() {
    for i in (0..100).step_by(2) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

#### Rust 1.1+

You can always write it out the old-fashioned way:

```
fn main() {
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < 100 {
        println!("i: {}", i);
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

Which can then be abstracted:

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn step_by<T, F>(start: T, end_exclusive: T, step: T, mut body: F)
where
    T: Add<Output = T> + PartialOrd + Copy,
    F: FnMut(T),
{
    let mut i = start;
    while i < end_exclusive {
        body(i);
        i = i + step;
    }
}

fn main() {
    step_by(0, 100, 2, |i| {
        println!("i: {}", i);
    })
}
```

Interesting historical side note, I believe that originally all the looping was done with closures like this, before iterators became extremely prevalent.

You can then take this and make it into an iterator:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct StepBy<T> {
    start: T,
    end_exclusive: T,
    step: T,
}

impl<T> StepBy<T> {
    fn new(start: T, end_exclusive: T, step: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            start,
            end_exclusive,
            step,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for StepBy<T>
where
    T: Add<Output = T> + PartialOrd + Copy,
{
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.start < self.end_exclusive {
            let v = self.start;
            self.start = self.start + self.step;
            Some(v)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in StepBy::new(0, 100, 2) {
        println!("i: {}", i);
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How can I add new methods to Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30540766/155423)

Comment: I was hoping for a more "elegant" and built-in solution but I guess that's what happens with new(ish) languages. Thanks!

Comment: @Sosdoc stepping by an increment is a highly anticipated addition! It just turns out to be complicated. What do you do for edge cases like exceeding the bounds of your type in either direction? Or handling stepping by zero? It's surprising the little details that are possible. Note that my solution has nothing to prevent you from misusing it. :-)

Comment: I know, I was just a bit perplexed that I couldn't find something I had been used to since I was fiddling with C.

Comment: You can always use `for i in 0..(n/2) { let i = i * 2; … }`

Comment: Still very useful, as `Iterator::step_by` forces us to use 64 bits, this is faster when we're sure we can stick with 32 bits.

Answer (score 5):

There is way using `let` "redefinition":

```
for i in 0..((n + 1) / 2) {
    let i = i * 2;
    // …
}
```

Or use `Iterator::map`:

```
for i in (0..((n + 1) / 2)).map(|i| i * 2) {
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think i'll stick to a while loop. But if you really want an iterator based method you could try this

```
fn main(){
    let (start, step, end) = (1, 2, 20);
    for i in (0..).map(|x| start+step*x)
                  .take_while(|&x| x<end){
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [crate `num`](https://crates.io/crates/num)

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies.num]
version = "0.1.25"
default-features = false
```

Since you only need the crate's basics, use `default-features = false`.

Rust:

```
extern crate num;

use num::range_step;

for i in range_step(0, 10, 2) {
    /*    */
}
```

`range_step` is generic over rust's integer types.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was asked, the [`itertools` crate](https://crates.io/crates/itertools), has become fairly standard as a dependency. You can do what you want very simply with the [`step()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.8/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.step) method:

```
extern crate itertools; // 0.7.8
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    for i in (0..=10).step(2) {
        println!("i = {}", i);
    }
}
```

In your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
itertools = "0.7.8"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `iterator_step_by` feature.

Here is an example of two threads running, one of them printing out odd numbers and the other even ones:

```
#![feature(iterator_step_by)]
extern crate thebook;

use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
fn main() {
    let handle = thread::spawn(|| {
        for i in (1..1000).step_by(2) {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    });
    for i in (2..1000).step_by(2) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
    handle.join();
}
```

Without this feature, you can also use a filter on the range:

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
fn main() {
    let handle = thread::spawn(|| {
        for i in (1..1000).filter(|x| x % 2 != 0) {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    });
    for i in (2..1000).filter(|x| x % 2 == 0) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
    handle.join();
}
```

Comment: Features are expressly **not allowed** in stable Rust, which this question is about.

Comment: Fair enough. I just added a filter-based approach.