# How to initialize multiple variables in a FOR loop in Rust

Tags: for-loop, rust, syntax

I want initialize multiple variables in a for loop, like for example something like this:
`for (i, j) in (1..=4),(10..=16).step_by(2){ println!("i = {i}, j ={j}"); }`

The result would be something like:
`i = 1, j = 10 i = 2, j = 12 i = 3, j = 14 i = 4, j = 16`

I have checked this post: [How to use multiple variables in Rust's for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302808/how-to-use-multiple-variables-in-rusts-for-loop)
but I haven´t found anything useful for me, I know I can use a while loop, but I find the ability to set everything in just one line much clearer

Answer (score 4):

The [`zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) iterator method, mentioned in the very answer you link to, creates tuples by pairing up elements of two iterators.  You can still use it all on one line; there is nothing that requires you to create the two iterators as separate statements.

```
for (i, j) in (1..=4).zip((10..=16).step_by(2)) {
    println!("i = {i}, j ={j}");
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e4ad623061fd4136257635452e873c41))

Comment: Thank you so much, I also learned about the izip! iterator tool (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669287/how-can-i-zip-more-than-two-iterators) which makes it look cleaner and allows to do this with more than 2 iterators. (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1fe7cd8059b9ac8ce7b0c1a36f54645)