# Is there a way to do a for loop that is neither iterative nor linear?

Tags: for-loop, rust

Can I write a Rust `for` loop equivalent to this C code:

```c
for(int i = 2; i <= 128; i=i*i){
    //do something
}
```

I'm only seeing things like

```
for i in 0..128 { /* do something */ }
```

or

```
let v = vec![0, 1, 2, /* ... */ ];
for i in v.iter() { /* do something */ }
```

Should I just use a `while` loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are C style for loops that step by a different amount each iteration possible in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823042/are-c-style-for-loops-that-step-by-a-different-amount-each-iteration-possible-in)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can I write a for loop equivalent to this C code:

That specifically, yes:

```
extern crate itertools;
for i in itertools::iterate(2, |&i| i*i).take_while(|&i| i <= 128) {
    // do something
}
```

But in general, no.  There is no single, *direct* equivalent to all possible uses of C's `for` loop.  If there's no way to write it using iterators then yes, you need to use a more general loop form:

```
{
    let mut i = 2;
    while i <= 128 {
        // do something
        i = i*i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can *always* create a custom iterator that does whatever unique sequence you need:

```
struct Doubling {
    current: u64,
    max: u64,
}

impl Iterator for Doubling {
    type Item = u64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.current > self.max {
            None
        } else {
            let v = Some(self.current);
            self.current *= 2;
            v
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let iter = Doubling { current: 2, max: 128 };
    let values: Vec<_> = iter.collect();
    println!("{:?}", values);
}
```

It's important to recognize that this logic (like the original C!) has nasty edge cases when the value is doubled beyond the size of the type.

---

In this *particular* case, you can also recognize that you have an exponential series:

```
fn main() {
    let iter = (1..8).map(|p| 2i32.pow(p));
    let values: Vec<_> = iter.collect();
    println!("{:?}", values);
}
```

---

If you want to get really experimental, check out [Lazy sequence generation in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16421033/155423). Adapted here:

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait, conservative_impl_trait)]

use std::ops::{Generator, GeneratorState};

fn doubling(mut start: u64, max: u64) -> impl Iterator<Item = u64> {
    GeneratorIteratorAdapter(move || {
        while start <= max {
            yield start;
            start *= 2;
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let iter = doubling(2, 128);
    let sum: Vec<_> = iter.collect();
    println!("{:?}", sum);
}

/* copy-pasta */
struct GeneratorIteratorAdapter<G>(G);

impl<G> Iterator for GeneratorIteratorAdapter<G>
where
    G: Generator<Return = ()>,
{
    type Item = G::Yield;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self.0.resume() {
            GeneratorState::Yielded(x) => Some(x),
            GeneratorState::Complete(_) => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean... *yes*, but that's not exactly helping Rust's reputation for being long-winded.  This is "using the death star to explode the planet to kill a spider" levels of overkill...

Comment: *sees latest edit*  Ok, now you're doing this on purpose.  :P

Comment: @DK. I mean, only a little bit ;-). However, as I mention in the linked question, I think the `GeneratorIteratorAdapter` will be a part of the standard library in *some* form, leaving the `doubling` function as "reasonably" small.