# What is the proper way to coerce an iterator to return a value instead of a reference (or vice versa)?

Tags: rust, iterator

The general setup is I have an array of values I'd like to `map()` and then `chain()` with 1 additional value. I've learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44427004/6844357) that the proper way to construct that final value is to use `std::iter::once`. **This works and eliminated the below problem, but I would still like to understand it better**.

In my broken, likely rust-anti-pattern-riddled example, I was using an array of a single element and then calling `into_iter()`. This produced a value / reference type-mismatch in the chain.

**Question:** What is the Rust-idiomatic mechanism for correcting this value / reference mismatch? Particularly if `clone` and `copy` are unavailable.

#### Background: Why is there a type mis-match to begin with?

This much I believe I understand. Based on the definition of [std::iter::Map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html), the item type for the iterator is `type Item = B` where `B` is constrained by `F: FnMut(<I as Iterator>::Item) -> B` (i.e. the mapped type). However [array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) defines the following 2 `IntoIterator` implementations, both of which appear to produce references.

```
impl<'a, const N: usize, T> IntoIterator for &'a [T; N] where
    [T; N]: LengthAtMost32, 
type Item = &'a T

impl<'a, const N: usize, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut [T; N] where
    [T; N]: LengthAtMost32, 
type Item = &'a mut T
```

Example demonstrating the issue:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Copy)]
enum Enum1 {
    A, B, C
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Copy)]
enum Enum2 {
    X, Y, Z
}

struct Data {
    // Other data omitted
    e1: Enum1,
    e2: Enum2
}
struct Consumer {
    // Other data omitted

    /** Predicate which evaluates if this consumer can consume given Data */
    consumes: Box<dyn Fn(&Data) -> bool>
}


fn main() {
    // Objective: 3 consumers which consume data with A, B, and X respectively
    let v: Vec<Consumer> = [Enum1::A, Enum1::B].iter()
        .map(|&e1| Consumer { consumes: Box::new(move |data| data.e1 == e1) })
        // This chain results in an iterator type-mismatch: 
        // expected &Consumer, found Consumer
        .chain([Consumer { consumes: Box::new(move |data| data.e2 == Enum2::X) }].into_iter())
        .collect(); // Fails as well due to the chain failure

}
```

Error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, Consumer> as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == Consumer`
  --> src/main.rs:52:10
   |
52 |         .chain([Consumer { consumes: Box::new(move |data| data.e2 == Enum2::X) }].into_iter())
   |          ^^^^^ expected reference, found struct `Consumer`
   |
   = note: expected type `&Consumer`
              found type `Consumer`
```

[Rust playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=85ef1672544f21a29dce56ccd4e22c55).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [**long-standing issue**](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25725) regarding this. The technical details are a bit heavy, but essentially, due to underlying, technical reasons, you cannot take ownership of a fixed-size array and return owned references without a lot of hocus pocus. This becomes obvious when you think about what a fixed-size array is and how it is stored in memory, and how you can get elements out without cloning them.

As a result, due to the implementations you found already, you can only get borrowed references. You **can** bypass this with `arrayvec` (as they have a sound implementation of `IntoIterator` for `ArrayVec` with owned types), or you can require that all your `T: Clone` and deal with it that way, at a cost of extra items in memory (temporarily; 90% of the time the compiler optimizes this away).

Comment: Rust edition 2021 will support `IntoIterator` for arrays. https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/11/edition-2021.html#intoiterator-for-arrays